# Checking drive healh of RAID 0 with MOBO built-in RAID

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, performance, raid

I have the following MOBO: `IPMTB-TK (Truckee) motherboard` for `HP Pavilion Elite HPE-490t`.

I have 2 WD Blacks in RAID 0 mode. I was wondering if there is a way to view the status of each drive and it's health?

I've seen some applications not being able to recognize the drives and determain their health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html), since you're probably using Intel Matrix Storage (or Intel RST), and that's a good free utility which supports reading from Intel's onboard RAID controller.